# Split data by corresponding date period list of string

Tags: python

I have a few problems when grouping by interval in date period list of string

```
date_period_list = ['2022/07/28 - 2022/07/29','2022/07/31 - 2022/08/01']
my_list = [{'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 40}, 
           {'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 30}, 
           {'date': '2022/07/29', 'value': 50}, 
           {'date': '2022/08/01', 'value': 20}]
```

My expected result:

```
my_list = [50, 90]
# Only SUM "value" by "date" date is in the corresponding range in date_period_list 
# ['2022/07/28 - 2022/07/29' => 50, '2022/07/31 - 2022/08/01' => 40+30+20=90]
```

Currently, I don't know how to do it and I want to ask for a way to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) from the standard library.

Idea: once the strings are converted to `datetime.date` objects they support comparison relations. For each interval a function which check if a date belongs to a certain interval is created. Then go through the collection of data and classify.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_period_list = ['2022/07/28 - 2022/07/29','2022/07/31 - 2022/08/01']
my_list = [{'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 40},
           {'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 30},
           {'date': '2022/07/29', 'value': 50},
           {'date': '2022/08/01', 'value': 20}]


# date format code
date_format = '%Y/%m/%d'

# shortcut: string -> date object
def to_date(date_str, format=date_format):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format).date()

# list of functions to check period
boundaries_periods = []
for p in date_period_list:
    # boundaries of the perdiod
    lower, upper = p.split(' - ')
    lower, upper = to_date(lower), to_date(upper)
    # add function
    boundaries_periods.append(lambda d, l=lower, u=upper: l <= d <= u)

# classification of data per period
# iterate over the data
out = dict.fromkeys(date_period_list, 0)
for s, v in [(d['date'], d['value']) for d in my_list]:
    # iterate over the periods
    for i, checker in enumerate(boundaries_periods):
        # classify
        if checker(to_date(s)):
            out[date_period_list[i]] += v

print(out)
#{'2022/07/28 - 2022/07/29': 50, '2022/07/31 - 2022/08/01': 90}
print(list(out.values()))
#[50, 90]
```

Remark: the anonymous functions `lambda d, l=lower, u=upper: l <= d <= u` **must** have keywords arguments (only those which belongs to the loop) to avoid side effects. Just to be clear: in this form will raise side-effects `lambda d: lower <= d <= upper` <- DO NOT DO LIKE THIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) for creating date range from `date_period_list` then check each date exist in `my_list` and if exist use value and sum with previous values.

```
my_list = [{'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 40}, {'date': '2022/07/31', 'value': 30}, {'date': '2022/07/29', 'value': 50}, {'date': '2022/08/01', 'value': 20}]

dates, vals = list(zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), my_list)))
# dates : ('2022/07/31', '2022/07/31', '2022/07/29', '2022/08/01')
# vals  : (40, 30, 50, 20)

date_period_list = ['2022/07/28 - 2022/07/29','2022/07/31 - 2022/08/01']
res = []
for date in date_period_list:
    f,s = date.split('-')
    ss = 0
    for d in pd.date_range(start=f.strip(), end=s.strip()).strftime('%Y/%m/%d'):
        for idx, tmp in enumerate(dates):
            if d == tmp:
                ss += vals[idx]
    res.append(ss)
print(res)
```

---

```
[50, 90]
```